# Is there a micro usb OTG otg to HDMI adapter available?

Tags: usb-on-the-go

can a tablet with a micro usb OTG port connect directly to HDTV hdmi? how about HDTV USB port?

Comment: I am planning to buy a phone with a USB-C connection port. Then use a USB-C to HDMI Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe slim-port and MHL are your only options for USB > HDMI.

The better options IMO are Chomecast/Miracast screen mirroring.